# Inneractive ads integration to Android

Tags: android, eclipse, listview

I'm in the later stages of my app and am wondering how I should get an Inneractive ad to work. I've tried their tutorial and it is not displaying ads.
here are the codes

AndroidListViewActivity.java :

```
package com.androidhive.androidlistview;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.inneractive.api.ads.InneractiveAd;
import com.inneractive.api.ads.InneractiveAdListener;
import com.androidhive.androidlistview.AndroidListViewActivity;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class AndroidListViewActivity extends ListActivity {

    LinearLayout linear;
    InneractiveAd addedIaAd;
    InneractiveAd bannerAd;
    InneractiveAd rectangleAd;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        linear = new LinearLayout(this);
        linear.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


        //adding banner ad - banner
        Hashtable<InneractiveAd.IaOptionalParams, String> adData = new Hashtable<InneractiveAd.IaOptionalParams, String>();
        adData.put(InneractiveAd.IaOptionalParams.Key_Keywords, "Entertainment");
        InneractiveAd.displayAd(AndroidListViewActivity.this, linear, "MyCompany_MyApp", InneractiveAd.IaAdType.Banner, 60,adData,(InneractiveAdListener) AndroidListViewActivity.this);   


        setContentView(linear);



        // storing string resources into Array
        String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);

        // Binding Array to ListAdapter
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, adobe_products));

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // listening to single list item on click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {

              // selected item 
              String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

              // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
              // sending data to new activity
              i.putExtra("product", product);
              startActivity(i);

          }
        });
    }
}
```

Singlelistitem.java :

```
package com.androidhive.androidlistview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SingleListItem extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);

        TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_label);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        // getting attached intent data
        String product = i.getStringExtra("product");
        // displaying selected product name
        txtProduct.setText(product);

    }
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="adobe_products">
        <item>Adobe After Effects</item>
        <item>Adobe Bridge</item>
        <item>Adobe Dreamweaver</item>
        <item>Adobe Edge</item>
        <item>Adobe Fireworks</item>
        <item>Adobe Flash</item>
        <item>Adobe Photoshop</item>
        <item>Adobe Premiere</item>
        <item>Adobe Reader</item>
        <item>Adobe Illustrator</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

error from logcat :

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.androidlistview/com.androidhive.androidlistview.AndroidListViewActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.androidhive.androidlistview.AndroidListViewActivity cannot be cast to com.inneractive.api.ads.InneractiveAdListener

There is no errors in the program but when i run the application in Eclipse ADT it says the application has stopped unexpectedly.Can any one let me know how make the inneractive ad banner to work as a list item in the list view in this program.

Comment: Post the error from your logcat

Comment: The exception is clear, why do you expect `(InneractiveAdListener) AndroidListViewActivity.this` to work?

Comment: I'm trying to display a inneractive ad banner in the Activity.java file when the application is made to run.For that it requires InneractiveAdListener.